# Enable capture attribute for file input depending on label clicked

Tags: javascript, html, css, input

I have the following form with two labels:

```
                <form method="POST" action='/process' enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <div>
                        <label for="file" class="upload-button"><i class="far fa-file-image"></i></label>
                        <label for="file" class="upload-button"><i class="fas fa-angry"></i></label>
                        <input type="file" id="file" name="file" accept=".jpg, .jpeg, .png" style="display: none; visibility: none;" onchange="$('form').submit();">
                    </div>
                </form>
```

I would like the input to remain as it is currently written if the first label is clicked, but for a 'capture="user"' attribute to be added if the second label is clicked.  Is there an easy way of achieving this?

Comment: Give the second `label` a class, grab it using js/jquery, give it a click event, inside the listener function use `setAttribute()` method on `input` tag.

Comment: Let me know if you need further clarification on any of these steps, or if you want to accomplish something else ..

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't really understand - could you give a brief example?  Also, will the attribute change happen before file upload attempt with this method?

Comment: Yes, the attribute changes once you click. Are you using JS or jQuery?

Comment: I am using jQuery

Comment: Updated the code to jQuery. Please add the proper tags to your question, so you get better help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, give the second label a unique class:

```html
<label for="file" class="upload-button second"><i class="fas fa-angry"></i></label>
```

Then, select it, and add to it a click event listener that gives the `<input />` tag a `"capture"="user"` attribute using [`attr()`](https://api.jquery.com/attr/) method:

```js
$(".second").click(function() {
  $("input").attr("capture", "user");
});
```

Running sample: inspect the input tag to see the change

```js
$(".second").click(function() {
  $("input").attr("capture", "user");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.0.0-beta2/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<form method="POST" action='/process' enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <div>
    <label for="file" class="upload-button"><i class="far fa-file-image"></i></label>
    <label for="file" class="upload-button second"><i class="fas fa-angry"></i></label>
    <input type="file" id="file" name="file" accept=".jpg, .jpeg, .png" onchange="$('form').submit();">
  </div>
</form>
```